# Swagger UI for file download as zip

Tags: rest, download, swagger

We are using swagger UI for displaying the  Spring MVC REST API request response. I have an API to save the folder as zip. I want to display the downloading status on the swagger UI. How can I do this? Any help is appreciated.
Or
How to display Zip File download status in swagger UI?

Comment: You mean like a progress bar for downloading the zip file?

Comment: yes something like that. It should show that downloading is completed!

Comment: Not sure it'll work at all at the moment given this - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/374

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use header in response as follow link http://swagger.io/specification/#headersObject
Here example:
[image]